# adderror behaves differently between before / after triggers

Tags: apex, trigger, triggercontext, before-trigger

I have written a trigger handler to prevent more than n incidents for a client(lookup to user) at any point of time. This handler behaves differently if choose (before insert, before update) i.e. the adderror exception occurs only after (n+1) incidents have been created but in case of (after insert,before insert) it works fine.So if the purpose of addError() is to prevent DML operations why does it allows that extra record in case of before events? Also how can I display a dynamic error message in a trigger context.

```
trigger CountLimit on Incident__c (before insert,before update,after undelete) {
    Set<Id> clientids = new Set<Id>();
    Map<Id,Integer> clientmap = new Map<Id,Integer>();

    for(Incident__c inc:Trigger.new)
    {
        clientids.add(inc.Client__c);
    }

    for(AggregateResult result:[select count(id) sum, client__c client from Incident__c where client__C in:clientids group by client__C])
    {
        clientmap.put((Id)result.get('client'),(Integer)result.get('sum'));
    }

     for(Incident__c inc:Trigger.new)
    {
        if(clientmap.get(inc.Client__c)>3)
        {
           inc.Client__c.addError('You can\'t open more than 3 incidents for '+ inc.Client__r.firstname+' '+inc.Client__r.lastname);
        }
    }
   }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the case of a before-trigger the query in the for-loop only returns three records in the AggregateResult, because the fourth record has not been inserted yet. In the case of an after-trigger, however, the record has already been inserted, so the query returns four records and the error shows.

I suggest that you change your code inside the last for-loop to:

```
if((Trigger.isUpdate && clientmap.get(inc.Client__c) > 3) || 
   (Trigger.isBefore && clientmap.get(inc.Client__c) > 2)) {
       inc.Client__c.addError('You can\'t open more than 3 incidents for '+ inc.Client__r.firstname+' '+inc.Client__r.lastname);
}
```

With regards to your dynamic message, you can't use object-relations this way in triggers. You will have to retrieve all clients first, add them to a map and then you can use them.

Comment: Thanks @koen, so I was defying logic here and it's best to put this handler under the events (after insert, after update, after undelete) for this particular scenario. Could you please advise on dynamic error message I mentioned in my original post? Because the error message converts to 'You can't open more than 3 incidents for null null'

Comment: No problem! If you decide to use after-events only, you can leave your code the way it is. I have updated my answer with a short explanation of what to do to get the dynamic messages to work, do you need an example?

Comment: hi @Koen, could you please help me in the test class below?It's throwing System.NullPointerException.

Comment: Koen, I think I get the issue here, until I annotate with @isTest(seealldata=true) I keep on getting this error.

Comment: At first sight I think it's related to the query for the thisUser variable. Why are you inserting the test user as a different user? Also, you're currently not using System.assert() anywhere. Have a look at that method in relation to test methods.

Comment: Hi @Koen, I have changed my test class as per your advice but still it's not working out until I annotate it with (seealldata=true). Please see the code below.

Comment: Can you tell me which line it's pointing to?

Comment: here is the log @Koen

EXCEPTION_THROWN [15]|System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY, CountLimit: execution of AfterInsert

EXCEPTION_THROWN caused by: System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object

Comment: UserRoleId = ur.Id, you use this line in CreateUser() but you don't set ur.Id in CreateUserRole(). If you want your UserRole to have an Id you need to insert it first and then use a SELECT query to retrieve it's Id.

Comment: I have changed the method definition of CreateUserRole() to insert the role and also of CreateUser() to soql the profile and insert the user but it still throws the same exception. My question - why does annotating the class with (seealldata=true) doesn't throw any exception ?

Comment: You're selecting a Profile, which you can only see when seeAllData equals true. You could mock the Profile instead.

Comment: Hi @Koen Please advise what do you mean by mock the profile. Doesn't setup data is available with or without (SeeALLdata = true) ?

Comment: Oops, you're right.. The profile should be available without SeeAllData=true.. I must admit that in that case I'm not sure either :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
  @isTest
public class IncidentLimit_Test {
    public static testmethod void testcountincident(){

        User usr = CreateUser('Ben','Bentaleb');
          List<Incident__c> inclist = new List<Incident__c>();  
        try{
        System.runAs(usr){
            Test.startTest();
            for(integer i=1;i<=5;i++)
            {
              inclist.add(new Incident__c(client__c=usr.id,Description__c='incident'+i));
            }
           insert inclist;
        Test.stopTest();
        }

    }

    catch(exception e){e.getmessage().contains('You can\'t open more than');}
        finally{System.assertEquals(5, inclist.size());}
    }
public static UserRole CreateUserRole(String name) {
    UserRole ur = new UserRole();
    ur.Name = name;
   insert ur;
    return ur;
}

    public static User CreateUser(String firstname, String lastname) {
    UserRole ur = CreateUserRole('Testing');
         profile pr = [SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE Name='Standard User'];
    User usr = new User(FirstName = firstname,
                        LastName = lastname,
                        Username = firstname + '.' + lastname + '@testing.com',
                        IsActive = true,
                        UserRoleId = ur.Id,
                        Email = 'testuser@testing.com', 
                        Alias = 'tusr', 
                        TimeZoneSidKey = 'Europe/Berlin' , 
                        LocaleSidKey = 'en_US', 
                        EmailEncodingKey = 'UTF-8', 
                        ProfileId = pr.id, 
                        LanguageLocaleKey = 'en_US'
                        );
        insert usr;
    return usr;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how my final code looks like -

```
trigger CountLimit on Incident__c (after insert,after update,after undelete) {
    Set<Id> clientids = new Set<Id>();
    Map<Id,Integer> clientmap = new Map<Id,Integer>();

    for(Incident__c inc:Trigger.new)
    {
        clientids.add(inc.Client__c);
    }

    Map<Id,User> usermap = new Map<Id,User>([select id,name from user where id in:clientids]);

    for(AggregateResult result:[select count(id) sum, client__c client from Incident__c where client__C in:clientids group by client__C])
    {
        clientmap.put((Id)result.get('client'),(Integer)result.get('sum'));
    }

    for(Incident__c inc:Trigger.new)
    {
        if(clientmap.get(inc.Client__c)>5)
        {
           inc.addError('You can\'t open more than 5 incidents for '+ usermap.get(inc.Client__c));
        }
    }   
}
```